# How to transfer file from server to server

Tags: php, linux

Can you please provide me some kind of small tutorial about how to get started with file transfering from one server to another server. Especially how to deal with downloadable links that do not end up with an extension.

Usually, its fine to deal with links like,

www.mysite.com/myfile.zip

but how to deal with files like

www.mysite.com/?fileid=21

How to tranload links like,

http://www.mysite.com/?fileid=21

regards,
aqif

Comment: Rephrased version of closed question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703323/need-explaination-of-a-php-code-snippet, fyi

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're running on a Linux server. If so, you can use the wget command.

wget www.mysite.com/?fileid=21

Comment: yes I am on linux... but I dont want to do this manually. like executing commant like         wget www.mysite.com/?fileid=21 every second. I want code a script.php that will do the job

Comment: Use the exec() function in your PHP script to pass-through this command to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Write a php script that uses wget or rsync to transfer/synchronise any files and schedule it in  cron.